# ArcGIS 10.1 - identify Vehicle Routes from Segment Counts

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, splitting, route

We have vehicle counts on every road segment in a small portion of our city, but we are trying to determine the route of individual vehicles on these segments. Is there an algorithm in ArcGIS 10.1 that can let us separate out the individual routes from our segment counts?
For example, if we know the counts in the attached diagram, we are trying to generate the two unique routes from that information.

This is like a reverse traffic-assignment method, from transport modeling.

The volumes are not especially high and segments are small, so we could probably brute-force identify trips, but we'd like to see if anyone has a better suggestion first.

[image]

Comment: For this particular example, there's no way to know which vehicle went where.

Comment: As mkennedy said, based solely on counts of segments traveled, there's no way to know which vehicle traveled where without making some assumptions like no segment can be traversed more than once by any one vehicle (as you have implied by your solution). I'm not aware of a way to make that restriction from a network analyst standpoint. Without it, I can see at least a dozen travel paths that could be generated using those counts.